# Benefit of using event listeners over functions callbacks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, events, callback

**Note**: The question here is specifically for the case of Matlab!

The context of this question is a Matlab handle class, which receives some data over a websocket, does some processing to that data and then forwards the data to some other classes, which registered themselves with callbacks.

A simplified version of this class is given below:

```
classdef ReceiverWebsocket < WebSocketClient

  properties (Access = private)
    dataReceivers_ % Stores the callback functions and their desired rate
  end

  methods

    function obj = ROSReceiverWebsocket(TOPIC, URI, varargin)
      obj = obj@WebSocketClient(URI, varargin{:});

      obj.dataReceivers_ = containers.Map;
    end

    function registerReceiver(obj, name, rate, callback)
      cb.name = name;
      cb.callback = callback;
      
      obj.dataReceivers_(name) = cb;
    end
    
    % Implement the abstract callback functions
    function onTextMessage(obj,message)
      data = jsondecode(message);

      for key = keys(obj.dataReceivers_)

        cb = obj.dataReceivers_(cell2mat(key));
        cb.callback(data);

      end
    end
    
  end
end
```

While researching how to implement such a functionality in Matlab, I also came across the concept of [event listeners and notifyers in Matlab](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html).

From this I understand, that one could re-implement the functionality presented above using a handle-class event and then call to `notify(...)` within the `onTextMessage(...)` function instead of calling the callback functions directly.

---

My question are now, if there are:

- any benefits of using the events listener functionality over direct callbacks?
- any disadvantages of using direct callbacks?

I especially was not able to find any information about how the notified event callbacks are executed, with respect to execution order, any execution delay or even execution in different threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, it depends on your use case.

Personally, I think the main advantage of using events is that you could have multiple listeners triggered by the single event (with no additional coding for you, see here for an example: https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13305-can-timers-trigger-a-single-event-that-many-objects-listen-to).

It also allows you to have callbacks with potentially different argument lists, whereas in your example the callback function must take only one argument, the data.

With regards to execution order (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/callback-execution.html#bu0b2f4):

> The order in which listeners callback functions execute after the firing of an event is undefined. However, all listener callbacks execute synchronously with the event firing.